# TypeScript Generic method check Interface and cast

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, casting

I would like to use differents generic methode based on object type. Here is my code Exemple :

```
export interface IStorable {
    Enable : boolean;
}

async GetItemStored<T extends IStorable>(toExecute : () => Promise<T>){//Some Code}

async GetItem<T>(toExecute : () => Promise<T>){//Some Code}


Main<T>(toExecute : () => Promise<T>){
    if(this.IsStorable(toExecute)){
        await this.GetItemStored(this.CastInStorable(toExecute));
    } else {
        await this.GetItem(toExecute);
    }
}

IsStorable<T>(() => Promise<T>) :boolean {
    // ???
}

CastInStorable<T, U extends IStorable >(() => Promise<T>) : () => Promise<U> {
    // ???
}
```

Could you help me write the two Functions IsStorable and CastInStorable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless you mark the promise in some way on creation, there is no way to know the result type unless you wait for the result:

```
IsStorable(value: any) : value is IStorable  {
    return (value as any).Enable !== undefined;
}
async Main<T>(toExecute : () => Promise<T>){
    let result = await toExecute();
    if(this.IsStorable(result)){
        // result will be ISortable beacuse IsStorable si a type guard
        let asSortable = result;
        await this.GetItemStored(()=> Promise.resolve(asSortable));
    } else {
        await this.GetItem(()=> Promise.resolve(result));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

The other approach of marking the toExecute function, could look like this:

```
type SortablePromiseGenerator<T> = { () : Promise<T & IStorable>; isSortable: true };
type NonSortablegenerator<T> = () => Promise<T & {Enable? : never }>;

....
IsStorable<T>(toExecute: SortablePromiseGenerator<T> | NonSortablegenerator<T>) : toExecute is SortablePromiseGenerator<T> {
    return (toExecute as SortablePromiseGenerator<T>).isSortable;
}

sortableGenerator<T extends IStorable>(toExecute : ()=> Promise<T>) : SortablePromiseGenerator<T>{
    let toExecuteResult = toExecute as SortablePromiseGenerator<T>;
    toExecuteResult.isSortable  = true;
    return toExecuteResult
}
sample (){
    this.Main(()=> Promise.resolve({})) // call with anything
    this.Main(this.sortableGenerator(()=> Promise.resolve({}))) // will fail at compile if result is not sortable

    // Ok call 
    this.Main(this.sortableGenerator(()=> Promise.resolve({
        Enable : true
    })));

    // Will fail at compile time, if the result conforms to the ISortable interface it must be wraped with sortable
    this.Main(()=> Promise.resolve({
        Enable : true
    })) // 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly, I shouldn't resolve the promise at this Time. May be il will be possible in other TypeScript version